# Bluetooth not working - Ubuntu 16.10

Tags: bluetooth, system, 16.10

I have Bluetooth built in on my laptop. But when I go to Bluetooth via settings it says "No Bluetooth Adapter found"

I even used commands to check if I have Bluetooth such as dmesg | grep -i blue and hcitool dev but still no luck

I have a Alienware M15X

Running Ubuntu 16.10

Comment: Please [edit] your quetion and add output of `lspci -knn | grep Net -A2; lsusb` terminal command.

Comment: Ooh the Qualcomm Atheros cards are not well supported unfortunately. My friend had a similar problem, except they added support for quite a lot of hardware in between kernel 4.4.x and 4.8.x. You *might* be able to customize the kernel if there is an obscure module somewhere that actually supports your network card.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok the problem was "Bluetooth" receiver was disabled in BIOS, so I just enabled it there. SOLVED!

Comment: Oh, your unit shipped with Bluetooth disabled? That's odd...