# Bluetooth not working But works after restarting the PC

Tags: bluetooth, ubuntu-drivers

As show in the screenshot below

[image: screenshot]

Bluetooth doesn't work says " plug in the dongle to continue " ... But it works after I restart the laptop ... I tried using `sudo service Bluetooth  restart`  still no effect. Similar problem happens with WiFi as well it says "adapter not found but works fine after restart..."

Here is another screenshot

[image: screenshot]

showing there is no **On** option to activate the Bluetooth

**EDIT:**
`dpkg --status bluez | grep '^Version:'` gives:

```
Version: 5.48-0ubuntu3.1
```

`$ systemctl status bluetooth.service` gives:

```
● bluetooth.service - Bluetooth service
Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/bluetooth.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
Active: active (running) since Thu 2018-11-15 14:09:02 IST; 34min ago
Docs: man:bluetoothd(8)  
Main PID: 3547 (bluetoothd)    
Status: "Running"
Tasks: 1 (limit: 4915)    
CGroup: /system.slice/bluetooth.service
        └─3547 /usr/lib/bluetooth/bluetoothd

Nov 15 14:09:02 rohit-HP-Laptop-15-bs0xx systemd[1]: Starting Bluetooth service... 
Nov 15 14:09:02 rohit-HP-Laptop-15-bs0xx bluetoothd[3547]: Bluetooth daemon 5.48 
Nov 15 14:09:02 rohit-HP-Laptop-15-bs0xx bluetoothd[3547]: Unknown key Disable for group Policy in /etc/bluetooth/main.conf 
Nov 15 14:09:02 rohit-HP-Laptop-15-bs0xx systemd[1]: Started Bluetooth service. 
Nov 15 14:09:02 rohit-HP-Laptop-15-bs0xx bluetoothd[3547]: Starting SDP server 
Nov 15 14:09:02 rohit-HP-Laptop-15-bs0xx bluetoothd[3547]: Bluetooth management interface 1.14 initialized
```

Comment: What happens when you turn it on?

Comment: the button doesn't work

Comment: Edit your question by adding the output of this command: `dpkg --status bluez | grep '^Version:'` and this command too: `systemctl status bluetooth.service`

Comment: The last command shows that your Bluetooth is active.
I think you should shutdown your PC then restart it and then run the command.

Comment: When i restart the bluetooth will work ... the problem is i have to restart everytime

Comment: But according to the output of `systemctl status bluetooth.service`, your Bluetooth is active and running now.

Comment: but it still says no Bluetooth found  plug-in dongle to use bluetooth

Comment: Check this: 
https://askubuntu.com/a/838912/822295

Comment: working as of now ... will observe it for a week and then finalise